# How is jQuery able to normalize currentTarget for IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

In an event handler in a standard compliant browser, `this` and `e.currentTarget` (where `e` is the parameter of the handler) refer to the element to which the handler is attached, which by the way isn't necessarily the same as `e.target`.

Problem is, there is no `e.currentTarget` in old versions of Internet Explorer.

In old IE, `this` in an event handler is simply the global object and `e` is undefined and `window.event.srcELement` is just equivalent to `e.target` and not to `e.currentTarget`.

Question is, what kind of magic is jQuery pulling off to make `e.currentTarget` work even in IE?

Comment: [I recommend reading the source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js).

Comment: jQuery add new properties to the event object, and pass the modified version to the event handler.

Comment: The question that is being asked is, where is the property coming from if it isn't available in oldIE? @LeCurious can you define what oldIE you are refering to? IE7? IE8? IE6?

Comment: Here's how e.target is handled: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/event.js#L481 And here's where currentTarget is: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/event.js#L371

Comment: IE6 to IE8 does not have e.currentTarget according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974942(v=vs.85).aspx and some version of IE don't make 'this' point to the element according to the last section of http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html but I don't know which versions.